# Angular 8 Recursive Form submit for Dictionary (dynamic strucure)

Tags: json, angular, recursion, formbuilder, ngtemplateoutlet

Angular 8 Recursive Form submit for json (dynamic structure).
I implemented Angular 8 recursive json(tree) display for dynamic json object but not able to get input data from Angular Form to component on submit since json structure is dynamic.

I followed [Angular 8 Recursive Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59388525/angular-8-recursive-form#new-answer)
but its good list obj, but I have to make it work for json object, below is my json object structure.

```
this.filterFields: {
"signature": "[a][b][c][d]",
"id": "start3",
"passwd": "going",
"url": "https://example.com",
"code": "ME_GOOD",
"type": "ABCD",
"main":{
"description": "development",
"id": "98gbnuikmvgy6",
"name": "satsba",
"type": "dcba",
"upload": "2019-09-04 18:17:23.222",
"by": "example@gmail.com",
"version": "0.1"}}
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.
My code is here : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ibi4w5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts