# How to create a recursive form with Angular 8?

Tags: recursion, angular8, angular-reactive-forms

I need to create a dynamic form with multiple nested items. I've found [this example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpnpa2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

but i'm not sure it's doing deep recursive since once i've tried to add more levels of nested items - the ui brakes down.

Here is the default json structure with my attempts :

```
 {
    key: "common",
    title: "main fields",
    group: [
      {
        key: "createdAt",
        title: "Create Date",
        type: "date"
      },
             //   group:[{
      //     key: "foo",
      //     title: "Foo",
      //     type: "select",
      //   },
      //   {
      //     key: "goo",
      //     title: "Goo",
      //     type: "input",
      //   },
     
      // ]
    ]
  },
```

So as you can see under "common" - i've added 2 more levels of groups - the first group works fine - but the nested group with key "foo" and "goo" it's working.

I'm pretty sure the problem is in the template / markup

```
<form [formGroup]="filterForm" class="filter-form">
  <ng-template #recursiveList let-filterFields let-fromGroup="fromGroup">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of filterFields">
      <ng-container *ngIf="item.group; else default;">
          // in this area i'm not sure it's iterate over deeper nesting...
          <p>{{item.key}} </p>
          
          <div  [formGroupName]="item.key">
              <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: 
          item.group, fromGroup: {name: item.key}, isChild:true }"></ng-container>
          </div>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #default>       
        
              <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="fromGroup.name">
                  <input [type]="item.type" [formControlName]="item.key" 
               [placeholder]="item.title" [name]="item.key" />
              </div>
         
      </ng-template>
  </ng-container>
</ng-template>
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveList; context:{ $implicit: filterFields 
 }">.
```

Comment: check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59391973/16930239)

Comment: it is quite easy to replace that horrible identicon auto-generated by gravatar for you, by uploading another image through the ["edit profile"](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/7752814) option. in case you were wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my understanding, there are two issues in the example you provided:

- The data structure.
- The template.

### Data Structure

These are the interfaces I understand from your example:

```js
interface Base {
  key: string;
  title: string;
}

interface Field extends Base {
  type: 'select' | 'input' | 'date' | ...
}

interface Group extends Base {
  group: Array<Field | Group>
}
```

So the JSON example you provided should look something like this:

```json
{
  "key": "common",
  "title": "main fields",
  "group": [
    {
      "key": "createdAt",
      "title": "Create Date",
      "type": "date"
    },
    {
      "key": "test",
      "title": "Test"
      "group": [
        {
          "key": "foo",
          "title": "Foo",
          "type": "select"
        },
        {
          "key": "goo",
          "title": "Goo",
          "type": "input"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

### Template

Let's look at a very simplified version of the form:

```html
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">
  
  <ng-container formGroupName="common">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="control; 
      context:{ controlName: 'foo', group: 'test' }">
    </ng-container>
  </ng-container>

  <ng-template #control let-group="group" let-controlName="controlName">
    <div class="col-md-3">
      <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="group">
        <input type="input" [formControlName]="controlName" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </ng-template>

</form>
```

The code won't work, why? Think about the `ng-template` as a function. If you want it to know about the `formGroupName="common"` it needs to be **declared within** that scope. What matters is the declaration context and not the invocation context, just like regular functions.

This is the working version of the above example:

```html
<form [formGroup]="filterForm">

  <ng-container formGroupName="common">
    <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="control; 
      context:{ controlName: 'foo', group: 'test' }">
    </ng-container>

    <ng-template #control let-group="group" let-controlName="controlName">
      <div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="form-group" [formGroupName]="group">
          <input type="input" [formControlName]="controlName" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </ng-template>
    
  </ng-container>

</form>
```

Things get trickier when you have nested and you need to use recursion.
That's why I think that the approach of using the `formGroupName` and `formControlName` directives in this scenario makes things more complicated than they are.

I suggest passing the form control directly into the input by providing the right path to it.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2hrzwc?file=src/app/app.component.html) is a working example of the idea based on your original example.